# Why do most centrifugal fans found in laptops have tiny blades?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

If you were to use a centrifugal axial fan instead, won't you be able to achieve higher flow rates and better pressures? It seems like the efficiency of these motors are very low.

[image: Typical centrifugal fan]

Comment: Depends on how you define efficiency if it is just temperature change and a small size then it does what it needs. Cost may/will be a huge factor. Is moving more air above what is needed useful... and why create more pressure than what is needed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lower pressure differential and lower speed per blade translates to lower noise levels.

Additionally, for this sort of applications, higher speed would mean higher torque (scales with square of airspeed) and that converts to higher power usage; many blades allow to keep a decent flow while keeping the pressure, and resulting torque low.

Both of these factors are important in laptops. And while better flow rate would be desirable, higher pressure is absolutely not needed.